# How to plot empirical CDF and theoretical CDF in one picture in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot empirical cdf (ecdf) and theoretical cdf using `ggplot2`. But, the theoretical cdf isn't available in R, so I have to define it.

Here is my data:

```
data1 <- c(12.20,23.56,23.74,25.87,31.98,37,41.35,47.38,55.46,
           58.36,63.47,68.46,78.26,74.47,81.43,84,92,94,
           110,112,119,127,130,133,140,146,155,
           159,173,179,194,195,209,249,281,319,
           339,432,469,519,633,725,817,1776)

df <- data.frame(data1)
```

And here is my code to plot the ecdf:

```
base <- ggplot(df, aes(data1)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "step") + theme_light()
plot <- base +
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Fn(x)",
    title = "Empirical Distribution Function"
  ) +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title()
plot
```

I also want to plot the theoretical cdf in the same picture with the ecdf (with the legends). Here is the cdf

```
\frac{\alpha^{e^{-\lambda x^{-\beta}}}-1}{\alpha-1}
```

where alpha = 273.811028, lambda = 29.834133, and beta = 1.135448

Can you help me to give the code for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat_function()` to draw a line where the function is evaluated for a sequence of positions along the x-axis. You can use rlang-style lambda notation to give the function as a formula, wherein `.x` represents the x position fed to the function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- c(12.20,23.56,23.74,25.87,31.98,37,41.35,47.38,55.46,
           58.36,63.47,68.46,78.26,74.47,81.43,84,92,94,
           110,112,119,127,130,133,140,146,155,
           159,173,179,194,195,209,249,281,319,
           339,432,469,519,633,725,817,1776)

df <- data.frame(data1)
alpha  <- 273.8
lambda <- 29.8
beta   <- 1.135

ggplot(df, aes(data1)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step", aes(colour = "ECDF")) + 
  stat_function(
    fun = ~ (alpha^exp(-lambda * .x^(-beta)) - 1)/(alpha - 1),
    aes(colour = "TCDF"), xlim = c(0, 1700)
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Fn(x)",
    title = "Empirical Distribution Function"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, the function is (alpha^(exp(-lambda * x^(-beta))) - 1)/(alpha - 1). I've tried in my R, but I got a warning message: "Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
Elements must equal the number of rows or 1"
So it didn't plot the cdf, only plot the ecdf. Why this happen?

Comment: Ah yes I see now the mistake I made in transcribing the function. I'm not sure why you get that error, it works fine with the updated function for me. Have you tried restarting your R session?

Comment: May I see the plot of new result? I have tried restarting my R but still get that error

Comment: I've updated the answer with the new plot